# Using regex to remove html elements using SAS DS2

Tags: sas

I am getting the below error while trying to remove all the html elements using regex in SAS. Can you please let me know what is the issue ?

```
Data HTMLData;
filename INDEXIN URL "http://www.google.com/";
input;

textline = _INFILE_;
/*-- Clear out the HTML text --*/
re1 = prxparse("s/<(.|\n)*?>//");
call prxchange(re1, -1, textline);
run;
```

ERROR: No DATALINES or INFILE statement.
ERROR: The *INFILE* variable has been referenced, but no DATALINES or INFILE statement was found.

Comment: That doesn't look like [tag:sas-ds2].  Why do you include that in the title?

Comment: Also - removed [tag:regex] as the issue at hand is unrelated to regexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `filename`, but you need an `infile` statement instead (or in addition).  `filename` is an open code statement, it's just establishing a link between a name literal and a file path.

```
filename INDEXIN URL "http://www.google.com/";

Data HTMLData;
  infile indexin;
  input;

  textline = _INFILE_;
  /*-- Clear out the HTML text --*/
  re1 = prxparse("s/<(.|\n)*?>//");
  call prxchange(re1, -1, textline);
run;
```

Comment: Thanks @Tom, missed that line!

Comment: If the REGEX does not vary do you need to PRXPARSE it each time?